# file_get_contents and &amp;

Tags: php, url

so this seems to be a common error, but I've tried everything and it just doesn't work!

My code currently looks like this:

```
$apikey = "XXXXXXXXX";
$search_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=$apikey&country=US&q=$item_title&restrictBy=gtin&alt=json";

$response = file_get_contents($search_url);
```

I've tried everything from urldecode to html_entity_decode/encode to just about every solution that I could find, but still, get the same error:

```
file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=XXXXX&amp;country=US&amp;q=THESTRING&amp;restrictBy=gtin&amp;alt=json) failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

as you can see, instead of plain-ol' & (ampersand) I get &amps

I remember having a similar problem, and the problem was simply that I didn't have "http://" at the beginning of the string. But as you can see, that's not the case here.

Thanks!

Comment: can you check allow_url_fopen is enabled in your php.ini file ? or try another url like $query=file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiFrfeJ8dKM');

Comment: allow_url_fopen = On in php.ini
When I do file_get_contents("http://www.google.com") I get no errors (and print $response works as expected).
Even doing file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi") works

Comment: They're not being changed to `&amp;`s, that's just to format your error message in the browser correctly.

Answer (score 0):

did you try single quotes so your test string would be taken literally? as in

```
$search_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key='.$apikey.'&country=US&q=$item_title&restrictBy=gtin&alt=json';
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it didn't work.

But I found out what did work (stupid me) - the string I was passing in &q=$item_title had spaces in them. I need to find a way to translate them to something that will work (plus sign maybe?), but that is basically what is causing the problem...

Comment: Now it seems the trouble is, when I pass an item title with spaces in it, it gives this error. I've tried "quoting" the item (single- and double), translating spaces to %20 and plus-signs, but it doesn't seem to work... any ideas?

Comment: have you tried with cURL ? curl is much faster and better than file_get_contents. can you paste URL with values withoug apikey ?

Comment: Okay, found the problem. Translating white-spaces in $item_title to plus-signs *did* work.

    strtr( $item_title, " ", "+" );

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove spaces from parameter like in my case:

```
search_jobs.php?catagory_select=1&keys=head of IT
```

Its not working when having space between the word "head of IT"

```
search_jobs.php?catagory_select=1&keys=head-of-IT
```

I've replaced space with "-" dash sign and its working now.

if you think you will require to make a lot of changes in script to replace all spaces then here's a quick way on the page that is being open like i was opening a page:

**"search_jobs.php?catagory_select=1&keys=head of IT"**

Now to repalce spaces automatically from the parameter "head of IT"  you need to add javascript code on the loading page "**search_jobs.php**"

```
    <script>
if(location.href.indexOf('%20') > -1){
    location.href = location.href.replace('%20','-');
}
    </script>
```

Add this code on top of page it will replace spaces with "-" dash sign automatically before to open a page.

Thank You

Answer (score -1):

The answer to my problem was quite simple:

When $item_title contained whitespaces, PHP threw an error. To fix this, all I had to do was add this to my code:

```
strtr( $item_title, " ", "+" );
```

Changes whitespaces to plus-signs. No more failed requests!

Thanks guys.